# Compare date from combobox with current date

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have a combobox with data from store:

```
fields: [
    {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
    {name: 'createDate',  type: 'string'}
]
```

Field `'createDate'` has format "03.05.2015", this combobox outputs only field `'name'`:

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'NameText',
    store: 'storeofnames',
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id'
}
```

I want next:

Combobox output: name + (if date in field `createDate` `>=` current date) add in combobox data from `'createDate'`.

Comment: You shouldn't store your dates as a string, it's harder to work with a date, if it's not really a date. If you have a date stored, you could compare it in `displayTpl` like so: `displayTpl: '{name}<tpl if="createDate >=' + currentDate + '">{createDate}</tpl>'`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this trick: in your model add item like:

```
{
    name: 'display',
    mapping: function(rec) {
        return rec.name + (new Date(rec.createDate) >= new Date()
            ? ' ' + rec.createDate
            : '');
    }
}
```

And in your combobox change displayField:

```
displayField: 'display'
```